# \DeclareTOCStyleEntries throws error unknown option

Tags: koma-script

I want to remove space between numbers and formatting title of entries in toc. But as written in the title, the command throws errors for both used options.

```
\documentclass[version=last]{scrreprt}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
    dynumwidth=false,
    entryformat=\em,
]{dottedtocline}{section, subsection, subsubsection}

\begin{document}
l
\end{document}
```

Comment: the `dottedtocline` style don't know these options, use `tocline` instead. Also the name of the first option is `dynnumwidth` with two n.

Comment: But I need dots after entry names and things written in description. How could I accomplish this?

Comment: tocline should offer that, check the documentation.

Comment: From the manual (page 393) on  `entryformat=command` : You can use this attributes to change the format of the entry. The value should be
a command with exactly one argument. This argument is not necessarily fully expandable. You **should not use** commands like `\MakeUppercase`, which expects a fully
expandable argument.

Answer (score 3):

Style `dottedtocline` only supports the attributs `level`, `indent` and `numwidth`.

By default `scrreprt` (and `scrbook` and `scrartcl`) uses style `tocline` for all entry levels. This style supports 19 attributs, eg. `dynnumwidth`, `entryformat` and `linefill`.  KOMA-Script class `scrreprt` sets attribut `linefill` to `\TOCLineLeaderFill` for `section`, `subsection`, `subsubsection`, `paragraph` and `subparagraph`. Therefore these entries get a dotted line between the entry text and its page number by default.

If you want to change the `entryformat` for these entries, use

```latex
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  entryformat=\em
]{tocline}{section, subsection, subsubsection}
```

I have removed attribut `dynnumwidth=false` (note the spelling), because its the default setting.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  entryformat=\em
]{tocline}{section, subsection, subsubsection}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

With a KOMA-Script class style `default` is a clone of style `tocline`. So you could also use

```latex
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  entryformat=\em
]{default}{section, subsection, subsubsection}
```

If you need a dotted line for chapter entries too, add the following code to the preamble

```latex
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  linefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill% initial value for chapter was \hfill
]{tocline}{chapter}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  linefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill
]{tocline}{chapter}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  entryformat=\em
]{tocline}{section, subsection, subsubsection}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

There is also a class option for chapter entries with dots. So you could use `\KOMAoptions{toc=chapterentrywithdots}` or `\documentclass[toc=chapterentrywithdots]{scrreprt}`.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[toc=chapterentrywithdots]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  entryformat=\em
]{tocline}{section, subsection, subsubsection}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```